# The statement of integration by substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For this method of solving integrals, it is given the following statement:

> Let  $~~g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R},~~~~ f: g([a,b])\to\Bbb R~~$ be two functions such that
>
> $1.~$ $f$ is continuos
>
> $2.~$ $g$ is differentiable with integrable derivative
>
> Then we have that $$\int_a^b f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, \mathrm dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t) \, \mathrm dt $$

It is necessary that $f$ is continuous?

For example, I met the following examples:

http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/08/06/prove-an-integral-formula-for-periodic-functions/

(Lemma 2.1/3) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e602/c172526c258b154cbd3ef7a2caeb5a4b8336.pdf?fbclid=IwAR2Nb65mPuTlLuer9v5ITPzEPfPxVQXlMXCW-oVovDepyYL0fS1zvYWA-AE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f$ need not be continuous.

Let me quote [Bagby](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1212763969):

> **Theorem.** Let $[a,b]$ be an interval in $\Bbb R$ and $g: [a,b]\to\Bbb R$ Riemann-integrable. 
>   Let $G:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a function such that $G(x)-G(a) = \int_a^x g(y) \,\mathrm dy$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $f:G([a,b])\to\Bbb R$ be Riemann-integrable.
>
> Then $$\int_a^b (f\circ G)(x) \cdot g(x) \,\mathrm dx = \int_{G(a)}^{G(b)} f(x) \,\mathrm dx.$$

Your Theorem (without the continuity condition) follows as an immediate corollary, since we can choose my $g$ to be your $g'$ and my $G$ to be your $g$.